# How to edit layers which are using via OSM Bright in Tilemill

Tags: tilemill, mapbox

How could i edit a map which is edited via `OSM Bright` in TileMill? Layers are in TM added via PostGis. OSM Bright it's simply built according to informations [here](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright). I need delete some roads also delete labels. I have deleted and edited .shp file in `ArcGis`from project folder of TileMill but after saving of the .shp file and starting TM there are no any changes. Thanks for help.

---

I think it could be resolve by editing of .shp but it's still without changes. Do you think that changes could be shown after "re-postGis" to pgsql.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you're styling in Tilemill is coming from PostGIS, then use QGIS to connect to your PostGIS database, and make the edits there.

Now I can't remember if you'd have to re-start Tilemill or not, but even if so, the data should show up as changed in Tilemill as it isn't 'cached' until you export / upload it as tiles.

Regarding user roles in PostGIS editing, try running the following in the PGAdmin SQL Window:

```
select * from information_schema.role_table_grants where grantee='yourUserName';
```

You'll then see your privileges on all the tables you have access to.

You can refine the query to find out what access you have on a given table by using a where clause with the above query:

```
select * from information_schema.role_table_grants where grantee='yourUserName' and table_name='tableName';
```

You can edit this table in QGIS if you have the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges...

Comment: Thank you. I can try it. I thought that i have to edit only .shp files which are saved in TM folder project (\users\documents\Mapbox\project\OSM Bright) and there are shp files which i have modified but without changes in TM project. I think you know what i mean. I will try to do it in QGIS

Comment: I'm still unclear as to your TM data source - did you add .SHP to the project, or PostGIS tables? If you used PostGIS as you mentioned in your question, you shouldn't have .SHP in the TM project folder... if you do, you can just edit those files...

Comment: Do you know how can i start editing in QGIS because it's not possible to start edit after connecting to my PostGIS database.

Comment: can you post the error message you're getting?

Comment: TM data source yeah i'm using PostGIS. OSM Bright have created build folder and also project into TileMill so it's connected to my PostGIS. In QGIS I'm not getting error message i just not able to start editing (i can not click to edit button)

Comment: @L.s. that's a whole different issue... not sure how to help you to be honest... there's docs like this one http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html --- have you edited shapefiles in QGIS before?

Comment: I don't know how it's possible but data in TM are connected to PostGIS for sure, but in project folder there are .shp files too. There are three types of shapefiles...osm-line, osm-point, osm-polygons...Yeah i have edited .shp files in QGis before and it still works i just have tried to add .shp file and it works so there is no problem with editing of shp files there is problem with editing data connected to my PostGIS database.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to make sure you're logging into PostGIS as a user with the proper privileges to edit data... can you verify that? ie SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, etc.

Comment: If am i logging into PosGIS as a user with the proper privileges in QGIS?? Where should i choose this option? I did not see anything similar during connecting to PostGIS. I'm not able to do any adjustments.

Comment: + I found in DB Manager this : Privileges
User has privileges:
create new schemas
create temporary tables

Comment: QGIS lets you log in as a valid PostGIS/PostgreSQL user, and will let you do to your PostGIS data what PGSQL determines that user can do... so you'll have to track down using PGAdmin what privileges you have...

Comment: Thank you i'm beginner in these things. So, i'm going to try to set privileges in PGAdmin. ;)

Comment: ok great! no worries, we're all beginners at something!!! and what you're doing here are good skills to learn!

Comment: Ok so I clicked to "GIS database" > Properties and there i'm able to see privileges and default privileges. In User/Group column is written "public" i clicked and chose to "all" for all (privileges/default privileges) but still not able to edit data in QGIS. Did i do something incorrect?

Comment: try the method i just added to the answer I provided above to use SQL to test your privileges on a given table

Comment: Hi there, I have tried the method you wrote in answer. I have tried it in PGAdmin as well as in QGIS (DB manager) but i still get only empty columns. See picture [here][1] and [here][2]. Thanks for your all advices i'm also looking for help using google but still nothing. [1]:http://i.imgur.com/ePmdtEP.png [2]:http://i.imgur.com/VUKfaE6.png

Comment: @L.s. instead of pointing to 'privilege_type' as the table, try pointing to the table you're trying to edit in QGIS, so you're query would look like: select * from information_schema.role_table_grants where grantee='skorwo' and table_name='nameOfTableYouWantToEdit';

Comment: I don't know how it's possible but in PGAdmin i always clicked to databases and then i chose my database right click>properties>privileges and default privileges i chose select, update, insert... just everything but it did not work. Now i have tried the same in schemas>public here i have used right clicked and chose everyting as well as in tables and now it works! I'm not sure if it's done correctly, but i can edit data in QGIS! Also after deleting privileges here i'm still able to edit data. I do not understand how it is possible. Anyway thank you very much for your help!!!;)

Comment: @L.s. alright good stuff!!!

Comment: Now just have to find what was the reason of these changes. Maybe that i added the privileges to "tables" but i'm still bit confusing about that.